# How to understand a function when limits are "clashed"?

Tags: functions, fourier-series

I'm working on Fourier Series problems, and my first step is to always draw and visualize the functions I am faced with.
If f(x) = -1 when -$\pi$ < x < $\pi$ and f(x) = 1 when 0 < x < $\pi$.
What happens with the region from 0 to $\pi$? How f(x) can be defined?

And now that we are all here. When trying to find $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$, do I need to calculate each twice? One for when f(x) = 1 and once when f(x) = -1? If yes, do I need to sum them up? My professor always gave us f(x) = 0 and f(x) = 1, so it was obvious what to do.

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly presented the problem? As you say, the function definition does not make sense. Or maybe there are 2 functions in the problem or maybe 2 problems..

Comment: You were 100% right, thank you. f(x) should have been -1 when -$\pi$ < x < 0.
Thank you. I'll delete the original post soon, but just wanted to make sure you see this first :)